# Erase Only Color Not Bitmap in Canvas

Tags: android, canvas, android-canvas, android-custom-view

Drawing App 
when i put bitmap background on view i fill the color using finger and i select the erase button that will be also remove color and car image what should i do please help me i only remove color not bitmap image from the background

[See the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gAVWS.jpg)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gAVWS.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Add two views one for background and one for color so if you erase in one view it will not affect the below view

Comment: can you give me some example

Comment: Create one frame layout and add two views, for below view set bitmap background and in top view do your drawing and erasing operations